# Excel 2010 VBA, why does formula display as text?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Why would the recorded VBA display the calculated value. Whereas my code displays the only the formula (but if I go into each cell and hit f2, then return, it shows calculated value).  I am using a table in Excel 2010.  Seems to be essentially the same thing:

Recorded code

```
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
Range("D8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""Value1"",[@[Program]])),""yes"",""no"")"
```

My  Code

```
Sub Formula_Insert
Dim MyTbl As listObject
Set MyTbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("NameofTableonSheet")
With MyTbl
   .ListColumns.Add 4
   .HeaderRowRange(4) = "Column D Header"
   With .ListColumns("Column D Header")
     .Range.NumberFormat = "General"
     .DataBodyRange.formula = "IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""Value1"",[@[Program]])),""yes"",""no"")"
   End With
End With
```

Obviously, the reason to insert the formula is so the user can see the formula and not the result.  I think the settings in options around formulas are all correct, and since the recorded code displays the calculated value, it has to be a problem with the VBA, no?

Comment: you need an equals sign in front of the If statement: .DataBodyRange.formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""Value1"",[@[Program]])),""yes"",""no"")"

Comment: Sorceri - you should move that to an answer so it can be marked as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in excel and you are not getting results, and the formula is being read as text, clear the formatting in the cells.  Then redo the formula